# Interrupt file-system operation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, samba

Assume that I have a directory that should contain only `jpg` files.

How can I prevent users from adding files that don't have `jpg` format to that directory?

My initial guess was to use `inotify` but it doesn't seem to give me the ability to interrupt/block the "operation" on the file / directory.

My second guess was to set the directory to read-only, when a user adds a file I'll check its extension then add the `write` permission to the directory before it gets an invalid access error.

> *Assume any file system that Linux supports*
>
> *This file system will be used by Samba if this is a helpful info.*

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to restrict write permission by extension.  A crude way to do it is a cron script which searches and deletes jpg every minute... but it's brutal :)

Comment: :'), but isn't it strange that this feature isn't supported?

Comment: Mhh not too strange, these kind of restrictions are usually implemented on the application layer. Also, a regexp filename restriction module could have a really big impact on the filesystem... and all it takes to bypass it is to change an extension.